# SpriteKit: Hashing a Recycled SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, hash, sprite-kit

I'm trying to detect collisions between nodes that have not collided before in my SpriteKit game by calling node.hash and storing new nodes in a set. I'm seeing that after some time, new nodes have the same hash as nodes that I had previously called node.removeFromParent() on.

I'm guessing that because I am removing from parent and recreating very similar nodes over and over, SK is automatically recycling some nodes.

How can I get a truly unique hash from nodes in SpriteKit?

Please let me know if further clarification is needed. I feel like posting my code wouldn't be too relevant to this post.

Furthermore, I am not able to reproduce this issue when I'm debugging with my phone attached to xcode but I have added logging that shows node.hash not being unique for newly created nodes. Anyone know why recycling behavior would be different with my phone connected to Xcode?

Comment: One solution could be to extend SKShapeNode and add a variable hasCollided, but I feel like this is over-engineering what could be done more simply with a proper hashing method.

Comment: When you say "truly unique" do you mean the contents (what the nodes represent) or could you just use the instance pointers as a hashing value?  Apologies for not being familiar with SpriteKit.

Comment: I'm also not too familiar with SK either. The contents of each of the nodes are the exact same. I believe the hash function is just returning the node's spot in memory, which gets reused.

I have worked around this in the mean time by removing the node's hash from the set just before being destroyed. But I still would like to know if there was a way of getting a different hash value for each instance of the SKShapeNode.

Comment: When you say it "gets reused" is that because the memory points are purposely recycled, or because the malloc algorithm is getting super lucky somehow (seems unlikely)? Seems like a variation of your current solution is the best you can do - maybe tagging each instance when you create it and leveraging objc_setAssociatedProperty or subclassing, like you noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding what a hash is and does.

A hash is not necessarily a unique value.  It is a one way function of some kind (not necessarily cryptographic) that takes arbitrary data and produces a value.  If the same data is hashed more than one time, it will produce the same hash value, not a different value.

Working against you, however, is the fact that the `.hash` value is *not* a cryptographic hash (which is somewhat computationally intensive). The quality of a hash function, cryptographic or not, is based on how frequently there are *hash collisions*.  A hash collision occurs when two *different* values produce the *same* hash.

Cryptographic hashing functions are selected, amongst other things, based on a low hash collision rate. The `.hash` function may have a high collision rate, even if your data is different, depending on your particular data.

A far better solution is to add a property to your nodes that can be easily checked:

```
class MyNodeClass: SkShapeNode {
   var hasCollided = false  // Publicly accessible property
}
```

I do notice that in other comments you say, "I am interesting in finding the proper hash."  I'd strongly recommend against this approach since, again, hash functions will definitely carry a computational load.  The better the function, the higher that load.

If what you are really looking for is a unique identifier for each node (rather than a collision tracker) then why not implement an internal property that is initialized from the initializer based on a class value that simply produces a unique, incrementing ID?

Answer (score 1):

`SKNode` is using `NSObject`'s default implementation of `hash` which just returns a memory address

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

let node  = SKNode()
let hex   = String(node.hash, radix:16)
let addr  = unsafeAddressOf(node)

print(hex)    // 7f9a21d080a0
print(addr)   // 0x00007f9a21d080a0
```

So basically, once a memory location is reused, the hash value is not going to be unique. Likely the difference between behaviour in debugging is due to compiler optimisations.

To get a unique hash you'll need to override the `hash` method of your `SKNode` and have it return something that is actually unique. A simple strategy would be to assign each node an `id` property at creation something like

```
class MyNode : SKNode {
    var uid:Int

    init(uid:Int) {
        self.uid = uid
        super.init()
    }

    override var hash:Int { get {
        return self.uid
    }}

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented, required to compile")
    }
}
```

If you start a counter off at `Int.min` and increment it towards `Int.max` you'll have to create `18,446,744,073,709,551,613` nodes before you run out of uniqueness.

Comment: Pedantic: Swift.Int changes sizes on different platforms. :) But yeah, probably not even 2 trillion objects will be created.

Comment: +1 @xtravar Good catch, yes. This assumes 2^64-1 possible values whereas on some hardware it will indeed be 2^32-1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you seem to be trying to determine if you’re colliding with new objects. What you could do is simply create a custom SKShapeNode object with the boolean property. This would remove the need to deal with colliding hashes, and instead provide a foolproof method of checking if the node has been dealt with.

```
class CustomShapeNode: SKShapeNode {
    var hasAlreadyCollided = false

    // Any required overidden methods
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to collide with new objects. As I said above, that is an option for getting around this, but I chose to go with a different work-around: I remove the node from the set right before I delete it. 

I am still curious why the .hash method doesn't work and I am interested in finding a proper hash.